# UIGestureRecognizer in iOS 3.1.3?

Tags: ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, uigesturerecognizer, universal-binary

I am working on making an existing iPhone/iPad project backwards compatible down to iPhoneOS 3.0.

My current test device is an iPod Touch with 3.1.3 on it.

The following bit of code is causing problems:

```
Class gestureRecognizer = NSClassFromString(@"UISwipeGestureRecognizer");

if (gestureRecognizer != nil)
{

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                               action:@selector(didSwipeLeft:)];
    leftSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    leftSwipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeRecognizer];
    _leftSwipeRecognizer = leftSwipeRecognizer;
}
```

According to Apple documentation UIGestureRecognizer is defined starting from iOS 3.2. So I expect `Class gestureReconizer` to be `nil` on previous OS version and that the following if to be skipped. However it does not skip. `gestureRecognizer` is not `nil`, the code inside the `if` starts executing and crashes at `leftSwipeRecognizer.direction` because:

```
-[UISwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e5720
```

This situation is quite confusing. I guess I am doing everything by the book. I try to check if a class exists before I use it, however the class which shouldn't be there, is there, fools my test, does not comply with its expected specs, and crashes.

I could, of course put a few `respondsToSelector` checks here and there to work around this crash, but it wouldn't be an elegant way to do it.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the UIGestureRecognizer class reference, under ["Usage Special Considerations"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW40), you actually do need to do an additional respondsToSelector check after checking if the class exists.

This is directly from the documentation:

> To determine whether a class is
>   available at runtime in a given iOS
>   release, you typically check whether
>   the class is nil. Unfortunately, this
>   test is not cleanly accurate for
>   UIGestureRecognizer. Although this
>   class was publicly available starting
>   with iOS 3.2, it was in development a
>   short period prior to that. Although
>   the class exists in an earlier
>   release, use of it and other
>   gesture-recognizer classes are not
>   supported in that earlier release. You
>   should not attempt to use instances of
>   those classes.
>
> To determine at runtime whether you
>   can use gesture recognizers in your
>   application, test whether the class
>   exists and, if it does, allocate an
>   instance and see check if it responds
>   to the selector locationInView:. This
>   method was not added to the class
>   until iOS 3.2. The code might look
>   like the following:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)];

if (![gestureRecognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(locationInView:)]) {
    [gestureRecognizer release];
    gestureRecognizer = nil;
}
// do something else if gestureRecognizer is nil
```